# No se ven nuevos "builds" de app iOS en iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes-connect

me pasa una cosa bastante curiosa, He creado un proyecto con Unity, lo he exportado a iOS y he configurado en XCode lo necesario para su compilacion (Team, certificado, un parametro para el hhtps en el info.plist, la versión y el icono de la Store en 1024 x 1024).

He generado el Archive, que lo hace de forma correcta y lo he subido a la Store sin publicar, para hacer un testeo mediante TestFlight, pero tenia un fallo y he necesitado subir una build nueva.

Esta misma app funciona perfectamente ya que la compilo sin problema si conecto un iPad o un iPhone directamente al MAC y hago un Run en vez de un Archive.

El caso es que cuando he querido crear un nuevo build, he seguido el mismo proceso, cambiando el nñúmero de Build y lo he subido a la Store.

Cuando en la web de iTunes Connect intento añadir el nuevo build, en ocasiones (no siempre), me aparece el build como pendiente, pero tarde o temprano desaparece y es como si no existiese, pero en realidad no es asi, esta subido, ya que si lo intento subir de nuevo mediante XCode, este me da un error diciendo que el binario ya existe.

He probado tanto a cambiar de build como de version, pero nada, no hay forma de subir la app modificada para enviarla al equipo de testeo.

¿Alguna idea?

Mil gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando subes un build a iTunes Connect puede tardar hasta 1 hora (he visto casos donde tarda mas) en aparecer en el sitio, hay que ser pacientes, principalmente el tiempo de espera para una app depende del tamaño del archivo. Ahora no creo que sea el caso ya que comentas que aparece procesando y después desaparece, mi recomendación es que revises tu email enlazado a la cuenta developer, Apple envía un correo con las razones por las cuales tu build no puede ser procesado, usualmente son problemas con el archivo info.plist

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es el caso, por ejemplo, el primer binario que subí no incluía el icono de la Store y al intentar enviarlo por TestFlight me lanzó un error de que no tenía el icono de marketing y lo corregí en XCode, pero este fue un error por pantalla y eso ocurrió anteayer a las siete de al tarde , el correo lo uso habitualmente. para temas de desarrollo y no ha llegado nada.

¿Hay alguna forma de ver las compilaciones subidas? ¿Se pueden borrar? He leído la documentación del portal de Apple y pone que se puede hacer, pero yo no encuentro ni opciones ni pantallas en iTunes Connect por ningún lado.

Answer (score 2):

Bueno, me respondo a mi mismo, me han entrado un montón de correos de golpe, se ve que había atasco en la autopista de la información :). Al parecer se ha estado produciendo un problema de firma inválida, revisaré el provission profile y el certificado porque será ese el problema.